# CountIf matching values in XML (T-SQL)

Tags: xml, t-sql

Is it possible to count occurences of particular xml node value (i.e. where Country = "United States") using T-SQL?

Sample xml:

```
<xml1>
    <xml2>
        <Country>United States</Country>
    </xml2>
    <xml2>
        <Country>Argentina</Country>
    </xml2>
    <xml2>
        <Country>United States</Country>
    </xml2>
    .
    .
    . --number of xml2 nodes vary
    .
    .
</xml1>
```

I can count the 'Country' nodes using:

```
myXML.value('count(xml1/xml2/Country)', 'float')
```

but what I also need to know is how many times the value reads "United States"

Is this possible?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out - myXML.value('count(xml1/xml2[Country = "United States"])', 'float')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much faster this way:

```
myXML.value('count(/xml1/xml2/Country[./text()="United States"])', 'INT')
```

Comment: Thank you, is it faster because it specifies that it's the text value it should look at or because of the 'int' vs. 'float'?

Comment: (1) It is faster because of the text() clause, (2) INT is a correct data type to count natural numbers.